# ¿es posible realizar operaciones con condicionales entre modelos?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

se que es posible realizar operaciones aritmética entre modelos ingresando datos desde dos campos diferentes, pero mi duda es si es posible que a partir de una condición se pueda ejecutar a continuación otro bloque de código. pongo mi ejemplo de modelo abajo, intente hacerlo de esta manera pero no hubo resultado.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

proceso_status=(('hc','Hc'),('af','Af'))
lente_status=[('argon','Argon'),('ecoline','Ecoline'),('mig','Mig'),('fall dual','Fall dual'),('argon elite','Argon Elite'),('neon','Neon'),('new classic','New classic'),('aviator','Aviator')]
turno_trabajo=[('mañana','Mañana'),('tarde','Tarde'),('noche','Noche')]


class tiempo_de_carro(models.Model):

    tipo_proceso = models.CharField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        choices=proceso_status,
        default='Hc',
        max_length=2,
        )

    tipo_lente= models.CharField(
        max_length=12,
        null=False,blank=False,
        choices=lente_status,
        default='argon',
        )

    tiempo_ciclo=models.IntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=True
    )

    total=models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=None)

    @property
    def sumar_valores(self):
        if self.tipo_proceso == 'hc':
            if self.tipo_lente == 'argon':
                return (3*self.tiempo_ciclo*24/60)
    
    def save(self):
        self.total=self.sumar_valores
        super(tiempo_de_carro,self).save()
    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tiempo_de_carro'
```

si se fijan en la ultima parte donde esta el decorador @property es donde estoy intentando obtener este valor a partir de los valores que pueden haber dentro de las tuplas busque info pero no encontre nada, me gustaría saber si es posible hacer una operación de este tipo y como, muchas gracias!